# My testing.spec.ts doesn't work. Error: Cannot make XHRs from within a fake async test. Request URL: http://xxxxxx/v1/products

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, mocking

I tried this test for testing my service:

Show this error:

> Error: Cannot make XHRs from within a fake async test. Request URL:
>   http://xxxxxx/v1/products

test file

```
it('should return reasonable json ssss', inject([ProductService, MockBackend], fakeAsync((service: ProductService, mockBackend) => {

    const mockResponse = {
        data: [
            { id: 0, details: 'All cats are lions' },
            { id: 1, details: 'Video 1' },
            { id: 2, details: 'Video 2' },
            { id: 3, details: 'Video 3' },
        ]
    };

    mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
        connection.mockRespond(new Response(
            new ResponseOptions({
                body: [
                    { id: 0, details: 'All cats are lions' },
                    { id: 1, details: 'Video 1' },
                    { id: 2, details: 'Video 2' },
                    { id: 3, details: 'Video 3' },
                ]
            })));
    });

    service.productsgetall().subscribe((facts) => {
        console.log(facts)
        expect(facts.length).toBe(4);
    });

    tick();
})));
```

-
    My service.ts

```
public productsgetall(): Observable<Products[]> {
                ...
 return this.http.get(Api.getUrl(Api.URLS.productsgetall), {
      headers: headers
    }).map((response: Response) => {
        let res = response.json();
        if (res.StatusCode === 1) {
          this.auth.logout();
        } else {
          return res.StatusDescription.map(aa => {
            return new Products(aa);
          });
        }
  });
}
```

Can you ask me, what is the problem in my code, how to write good testing?

My edit code:

> TypeError: done.fail is not a function

```
 it('should return reasonable json ssss', (done) => {
        inject([ProductService, MockBackend], async((service: ProductService, mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
                const mockResponse = {
                data: [
                    { id: 0, details: 'All cats are lions' },
                    { id: 1, details: 'Video 1' },
                    { id: 2, details: 'Video 2' },
                    { id: 3, details: 'Video 3' },
                ]
            };
                mockBackend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
                connection.mockRespond(new Response(
                    new ResponseOptions({
                        body: [
                    { id: 0, details: 'All cats are lions' },
                    { id: 1, details: 'Video 1' },
                    { id: 2, details: 'Video 2' },
                    { id: 3, details: 'Video 3' },
                        ]
                    })));
            });

            service.productsgetall().subscribe(facts=> {
                console.log(facts);
                console.log(facts[0]);
                expect(facts[0].details).toEqual('ffff');
                done();
            });
        }))();
    });
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1BU7.png)

Comment: What is problem in your code and how to write good testing?

Comment: You should mock the http get method and after test if the return is according to your mocked return from the get.

Comment: Yes, I edit my post. thnx

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly says that you cannot make XHR requests using `fakeAsync`.

Use `async` instead of `fakeAsync`

```
it('.....', inject([ProductService, MockBackend], async((service: ProductService, mockBackend) => {

    .................

    service.productsgetall().subscribe((facts) => {
        console.log(facts)
        expect(facts.length).toBe(4);
    });

    tick();      // tick might not work with async
})));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I change this and the error: `TypeError: done.fail is not a function`

Comment: I don't write anyone `done()`. This is my post for this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605994/my-testing-spec-ts-doesnt-work-error-cannot-make-xhrs-from-within-a-fake-asyn

Comment: Have you any idea please?